# Async debugging features are unavailable in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, async-await

When running my Windows Phone 8 app I see the following WARNING message in the Output window in VS 2013 Ultimate RC2:

*WARNING: Async debugging features are unavailable for this debug session because ETW event collection could not be enabled.*

How can I correct this warning and make Async debugging features available to me?

Comment: Have a look over this thread : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dbcb1c49-bf97-456b-b3ba-ce6350356dd0/warning-async-debugging-features-are-unavailable-for-this-debug-session-because-etw-event?forum=wptools

Comment: RC? That's not a build you should use any more.